# SpecFlow project load failed

Tags: visual-studio, build, specflow

I have a project with tests based on SpecFlow. Sometimes there is an issue that a working source code (works on other computers and build server) fails to load in Visual Studio 2015 with an info `load failed` in Solution Explorer and following error message on Output console:

`C:\Project\Tests.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Project\packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Project\Tests.csproj`

Project uses:

- SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2015 (VS extension)
- SpecFlow (nuget package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with project file (csproj). It was manually extended with `TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets` like follows:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets" />
```

But when directories were cleaned (e.g. by git reset hard), there were no packages, so project could not be loaded to perform the nuget restore.

The solution was to extend `Import` with a condition `Exists`.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets" 
    Condition="Exists('..\packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0\tools\TechTalk.SpecFlow.targets')" />
```